# How to make my radio buttons have square format

Tags: html, css

I need my radio buttons to have a square format, maintaining the background color of each one.

What I tried was to add in ".custom-radios input [type =" radio "] + label span":

> -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
>
> -moz-appearance: checkbox;
>
> -ms-appearance: checkbox;

But this takes away the background color.

```css
.custom-radios div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-3 + label span {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-4 + label span {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]:checked + label span img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="color-3" name="color" value="color-3">
    <label for="color-3">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="color-4" name="color" value="color-4">
    <label for="color-4">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you going out of your way to make radio buttons look like checkboxes?

Comment: `border-radius: 50%;` probably doesn't help ;)

Comment: @j08691 because the person who needs the project requires me to be square :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove border radius:50%;

```css
.custom-radios div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-3 + label span {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#color-4 + label span {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]:checked + label span img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="color-3" name="color" value="color-3">
    <label for="color-3">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="color-4" name="color" value="color-4">
    <label for="color-4">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: #aaaaaa;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  display: block;
}

input[type="radio"]:disabled:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tycL7jpb/).

Answer (score 0):

Just give border-radius 0%

```
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```